# OneDrive automatically unlinks synchronized SharePoint folders

Tags: sharepoint-online, sync, synchronisation, onedrive

We started using SharePoint Online, in combination with file management in Teams. 
For most users, completely working in an online SharePoint environment is not ideal, so some of their SharePoint-folders are synced to OneDrive so they can access the folders in Windows Explorer. 

Some users experience an issue where suddenly all folders stop syncing. 
Checking settings in OneDrive, it turns out all synced Sharepoint locations are gone, except for their personal folder. 
 
*(I dont have a screenshot of the issue, but let's say before the problem all folders are there, and when the problem happens suddenly all encircled folders are gone)* 
 [image]

It happens randomly: a user logs into their computer, and suddenly OneDrive synchronized locations are gone. We then have to remove the old folders in Windows Explorer and resync everything 

Has anyone expierenced this? Or is there a way to gather/find logfiles for SharePoint to OneDrive sync?

I can't find much information. 

We tried:

- Syncing smaller subfolders from SharePoint
- Delete and re-add the account to OneDrive
- Checkdisk
- Reinstall OneDrive
- Reinstall the entire laptop from factory default

Answer (score 0):

For end users, it’s not feasible to see the OneDrive Activities Log files on local computers.

It is recommended that you can Restore OneDrive, files Restore helps Office 365 subscribers undo all the actions that occurred on both files and folders within **the last 30 days**. For your reference: **[Restore your OneDrive](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/restore-your-onedrive-fa231298-759d-41cf-bcd0-25ac53eb8a15?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)**.